# How to find most frequent noun following the word 'the'?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, corpus, pos-tagger

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

tagged = brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
```

I understand that to find the most frequent word following 'the' is done like so

```
cfd3 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.bigrams(brown.words())

cfd3['the'].max()
```

however, how would one go about finding the most frequent noun following the word 'the'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a `FreqDist` that counts only the nouns that follow the word "the".

The Brown corpus has a very rich tagset, so let's simplify things by asking for the simplified "universal" tagset. All nouns are now tagged `"NOUN"`.

```
>>> noundist = nltk.FreqDist(w2 for ((w1, t1), (w2, t2)) in 
            nltk.bigrams(brown.tagged_words(tagset="universal"))
            if w1.lower() == "the" and t2 == "NOUN")
>>> noundist.most_common(10)
[('world', 346), ('time', 250), ('way', 236), ('end', 206), ('fact', 194), ('state', 190), 
('man', 176), ('door', 172), ('house', 152), ('city', 127)]
```

The comprehension unpacks the two `word, tag` tuples that form the bigram: `(w1, t1), (w2, t2)`; checks that the first word (lowercased) is "the" and the second is tagged "NOUN"; and if so, passes the second word (so, `w2` only) to be counted by the `FreqDist`.

Comment: this solution is so much easier to understand thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
>>> cfd3 = ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.bigrams(brown.tagged_words()))
>>> cfd3[('the', 'AT')].max()
(u'same', u'AP')
```

But do note, that if you haven't processed your bigram inputs after tagging the words, you might get different results for differently grained tags (fine vs coarse-grain tags) and capitalization:

```
>>> cfd3[('The', 'AT')].max()
(u'first', u'OD')
>>> cfd3[('the', 'AT-TL')].max()
(u'United', u'VBN-TL')
```

Possibly the one-liner droid you're looking for is:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
>>> cfd3 = ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.bigrams(brown.tagged_words()))
>>> next(word_after_the for ((word_after_the, tag), count) in cfd3[('the', 'AT')].most_common() if tag.startswith('NN'))
u'world'
```

---

Going into the one liner:

```
# Returns a freqdist dictionary of the words conditioned by the fact that it follows after "the" with the "AT" tag
>>> cfd3[('the', 'AT')] 
FreqDist({(u'same', u'AP'): 596, (u'first', u'OD'): 535, (u'other', u'AP'): 383, (u'``', u'``'): 365, (u'world', u'NN'): 334, (u'United', u'VBN-TL'): 333, (u'most', u'QL'): 327, (u'time', u'NN'): 242, (u'two', u'CD'): 230, (u'way', u'NN'): 224, ...})
```

Then:

```
# Returns a list of tuples of the words in the dict and its count
>>> cfd3[('the', 'AT')].most_common()
```

And similarly:

```
# Unpacking the list of tuples
>>> [word_after_the for (word_after_the, tag), count in cfd3[('the', 'AT')].most_common()]
```

Afterwards:

```
# Filtering words that are nouns
>>> [word_after_the for (word_after_the, tag), count in cfd3[('the', 'AT')].most_common() if tag.startswith('NN')]
```

Finally:

```
# Only retrieving the first noun
>>> next(word_after_the for (word_after_the, tag), count in cfd3[('the', 'AT')].most_common() if tag.startswith('NN')) u'world'
```

---

If we use the [Universal POS tags](http://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/):

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
>>> cfd3 = ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.bigrams(brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')))
>>> next(word_after_the for (word_after_the, tag), count in cfd3[('the', 'DET')].most_common() if tag == 'NOUN')
u'world'
```

We'll use the `'DET'` tag instead of the `'AT'` tag, and `'NOUN'` instead of `'NN*'`. The `'AT'` tag is particular to the brown corpus, see:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> dir(nltk.help)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_format_tagset', '_print_entries', 'brown_tagset', 'claws5_tagset', 'load', 'print_function', 're', 'upenn_tagset', 'wrap']
>>> nltk.help.brown_tagset()
(: opening parenthesis
    (
): closing parenthesis
    )
*: negator
    not n't
,: comma
    ,
--: dash
    --
.: sentence terminator
    . ? ; ! :
:: colon
    :
ABL: determiner/pronoun, pre-qualifier
    quite such rather
ABN: determiner/pronoun, pre-quantifier
    all half many nary
ABX: determiner/pronoun, double conjunction or pre-quantifier
    both
AP: determiner/pronoun, post-determiner
    many other next more last former little several enough most least only
    very few fewer past same Last latter less single plenty 'nough lesser
    certain various manye next-to-last particular final previous present
    nuf
AP$: determiner/pronoun, post-determiner, genitive
    other's
AP+AP: determiner/pronoun, post-determiner, hyphenated pair
    many-much
AT: article
    the an no a every th' ever' ye
BE: verb 'to be', infinitive or imperative
    be
BED: verb 'to be', past tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    were
BED*: verb 'to be', past tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural, negated
    weren't
BEDZ: verb 'to be', past tense, 1st and 3rd person singular
    was
BEDZ*: verb 'to be', past tense, 1st and 3rd person singular, negated
    wasn't
BEG: verb 'to be', present participle or gerund
    being
BEM: verb 'to be', present tense, 1st person singular
    am
BEM*: verb 'to be', present tense, 1st person singular, negated
    ain't
BEN: verb 'to be', past participle
    been
BER: verb 'to be', present tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    are art
BER*: verb 'to be', present tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural, negated
    aren't ain't
BEZ: verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    is
BEZ*: verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular, negated
    isn't ain't
CC: conjunction, coordinating
    and or but plus & either neither nor yet 'n' and/or minus an'
CD: numeral, cardinal
    two one 1 four 2 1913 71 74 637 1937 8 five three million 87-31 29-5
    seven 1,119 fifty-three 7.5 billion hundred 125,000 1,700 60 100 six
    ...
CD$: numeral, cardinal, genitive
    1960's 1961's .404's
CS: conjunction, subordinating
    that as after whether before while like because if since for than altho
    until so unless though providing once lest s'posin' till whereas
    whereupon supposing tho' albeit then so's 'fore
DO: verb 'to do', uninflected present tense, infinitive or imperative
    do dost
DO*: verb 'to do', uninflected present tense or imperative, negated
    don't
DO+PPSS: verb 'to do', past or present tense + pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    d'you
DOD: verb 'to do', past tense
    did done
DOD*: verb 'to do', past tense, negated
    didn't
DOZ: verb 'to do', present tense, 3rd person singular
    does
DOZ*: verb 'to do', present tense, 3rd person singular, negated
    doesn't don't
DT: determiner/pronoun, singular
    this each another that 'nother
DT$: determiner/pronoun, singular, genitive
    another's
DT+BEZ: determiner/pronoun + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    that's
DT+MD: determiner/pronoun + modal auxillary
    that'll this'll
DTI: determiner/pronoun, singular or plural
    any some
DTS: determiner/pronoun, plural
    these those them
DTS+BEZ: pronoun, plural + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    them's
DTX: determiner, pronoun or double conjunction
    neither either one
EX: existential there
    there
EX+BEZ: existential there + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    there's
EX+HVD: existential there + verb 'to have', past tense
    there'd
EX+HVZ: existential there + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    there's
EX+MD: existential there + modal auxillary
    there'll there'd
FW-*: foreign word: negator
    pas non ne
FW-AT: foreign word: article
    la le el un die der ein keine eine das las les Il
FW-AT+NN: foreign word: article + noun, singular, common
    l'orchestre l'identite l'arcade l'ange l'assistance l'activite
    L'Universite l'independance L'Union L'Unita l'osservatore
FW-AT+NP: foreign word: article + noun, singular, proper
    L'Astree L'Imperiale
FW-BE: foreign word: verb 'to be', infinitive or imperative
    sit
FW-BER: foreign word: verb 'to be', present tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    sind sunt etes
FW-BEZ: foreign word: verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    ist est
FW-CC: foreign word: conjunction, coordinating
    et ma mais und aber och nec y
FW-CD: foreign word: numeral, cardinal
    une cinq deux sieben unam zwei
FW-CS: foreign word: conjunction, subordinating
    bevor quam ma
FW-DT: foreign word: determiner/pronoun, singular
    hoc
FW-DT+BEZ: foreign word: determiner + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    c'est
FW-DTS: foreign word: determiner/pronoun, plural
    haec
FW-HV: foreign word: verb 'to have', present tense, not 3rd person singular
    habe
FW-IN: foreign word: preposition
    ad de en a par con dans ex von auf super post sine sur sub avec per
    inter sans pour pendant in di
FW-IN+AT: foreign word: preposition + article
    della des du aux zur d'un del dell'
FW-IN+NN: foreign word: preposition + noun, singular, common
    d'etat d'hotel d'argent d'identite d'art
FW-IN+NP: foreign word: preposition + noun, singular, proper
    d'Yquem d'Eiffel
FW-JJ: foreign word: adjective
    avant Espagnol sinfonica Siciliana Philharmonique grand publique haute
    noire bouffe Douce meme humaine bel serieuses royaux anticus presto
    Sovietskaya Bayerische comique schwarzen ...
FW-JJR: foreign word: adjective, comparative
    fortiori
FW-JJT: foreign word: adjective, superlative
    optimo
FW-NN: foreign word: noun, singular, common
    ballet esprit ersatz mano chatte goutte sang Fledermaus oud def kolkhoz
    roi troika canto boite blutwurst carne muzyka bonheur monde piece force
    ...
FW-NN$: foreign word: noun, singular, common, genitive
    corporis intellectus arte's dei aeternitatis senioritatis curiae
    patronne's chambre's
FW-NNS: foreign word: noun, plural, common
    al culpas vopos boites haflis kolkhozes augen tyrannis alpha-beta-
    gammas metis banditos rata phis negociants crus Einsatzkommandos
    kamikaze wohaws sabinas zorrillas palazzi engages coureurs corroborees
    yori Ubermenschen ...
FW-NP: foreign word: noun, singular, proper
    Karshilama Dieu Rundfunk Afrique Espanol Afrika Spagna Gott Carthago
    deus
FW-NPS: foreign word: noun, plural, proper
    Svenskarna Atlantes Dieux
FW-NR: foreign word: noun, singular, adverbial
    heute morgen aujourd'hui hoy
FW-OD: foreign word: numeral, ordinal
    18e 17e quintus
FW-PN: foreign word: pronoun, nominal
    hoc
FW-PP$: foreign word: determiner, possessive
    mea mon deras vos
FW-PPL: foreign word: pronoun, singular, reflexive
    se
FW-PPL+VBZ: foreign word: pronoun, singular, reflexive + verb, present tense, 3rd person singular
    s'excuse s'accuse
FW-PPO: pronoun, personal, accusative
    lui me moi mi
FW-PPO+IN: foreign word: pronoun, personal, accusative + preposition
    mecum tecum
FW-PPS: foreign word: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular
    il
FW-PPSS: foreign word: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    ich vous sie je
FW-PPSS+HV: foreign word: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to have', present tense, not 3rd person singular
    j'ai
FW-QL: foreign word: qualifier
    minus
FW-RB: foreign word: adverb
    bas assai deja um wiederum cito velociter vielleicht simpliciter non zu
    domi nuper sic forsan olim oui semper tout despues hors
FW-RB+CC: foreign word: adverb + conjunction, coordinating
    forisque
FW-TO+VB: foreign word: infinitival to + verb, infinitive
    d'entretenir
FW-UH: foreign word: interjection
    sayonara bien adieu arigato bonjour adios bueno tchalo ciao o
FW-VB: foreign word: verb, present tense, not 3rd person singular, imperative or infinitive
    nolo contendere vive fermate faciunt esse vade noli tangere dites duces
    meminisse iuvabit gosaimasu voulez habla ksu'u'peli'afo lacheln miuchi
    say allons strafe portant
FW-VBD: foreign word: verb, past tense
    stabat peccavi audivi
FW-VBG: foreign word: verb, present participle or gerund
    nolens volens appellant seq. obliterans servanda dicendi delenda
FW-VBN: foreign word: verb, past participle
    vue verstrichen rasa verboten engages
FW-VBZ: foreign word: verb, present tense, 3rd person singular
    gouverne sinkt sigue diapiace
FW-WDT: foreign word: WH-determiner
    quo qua quod que quok
FW-WPO: foreign word: WH-pronoun, accusative
    quibusdam
FW-WPS: foreign word: WH-pronoun, nominative
    qui
HV: verb 'to have', uninflected present tense, infinitive or imperative
    have hast
HV*: verb 'to have', uninflected present tense or imperative, negated
    haven't ain't
HV+TO: verb 'to have', uninflected present tense + infinitival to
    hafta
HVD: verb 'to have', past tense
    had
HVD*: verb 'to have', past tense, negated
    hadn't
HVG: verb 'to have', present participle or gerund
    having
HVN: verb 'to have', past participle
    had
HVZ: verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    has hath
HVZ*: verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular, negated
    hasn't ain't
IN: preposition
    of in for by considering to on among at through with under into
    regarding than since despite according per before toward against as
    after during including between without except upon out over ...
IN+IN: preposition, hyphenated pair
    f'ovuh
IN+PPO: preposition + pronoun, personal, accusative
    t'hi-im
JJ: adjective
    ecent over-all possible hard-fought favorable hard meager fit such
    widespread outmoded inadequate ambiguous grand clerical effective
    orderly federal foster general proportionate ...
JJ$: adjective, genitive
    Great's
JJ+JJ: adjective, hyphenated pair
    big-large long-far
JJR: adjective, comparative
    greater older further earlier later freer franker wider better deeper
    firmer tougher faster higher bigger worse younger lighter nicer slower
    happier frothier Greater newer Elder ...
JJR+CS: adjective + conjunction, coordinating
    lighter'n
JJS: adjective, semantically superlative
    top chief principal northernmost master key head main tops utmost
    innermost foremost uppermost paramount topmost
JJT: adjective, superlative
    best largest coolest calmest latest greatest earliest simplest
    strongest newest fiercest unhappiest worst youngest worthiest fastest
    hottest fittest lowest finest smallest staunchest ...
MD: modal auxillary
    should may might will would must can could shall ought need wilt
MD*: modal auxillary, negated
    cannot couldn't wouldn't can't won't shouldn't shan't mustn't musn't
MD+HV: modal auxillary + verb 'to have', uninflected form
    shouldda musta coulda must've woulda could've
MD+PPSS: modal auxillary + pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    willya
MD+TO: modal auxillary + infinitival to
    oughta
NN: noun, singular, common
    failure burden court fire appointment awarding compensation Mayor
    interim committee fact effect airport management surveillance jail
    doctor intern extern night weekend duty legislation Tax Office ...
NN$: noun, singular, common, genitive
    season's world's player's night's chapter's golf's football's
    baseball's club's U.'s coach's bride's bridegroom's board's county's
    firm's company's superintendent's mob's Navy's ...
NN+BEZ: noun, singular, common + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    water's camera's sky's kid's Pa's heat's throat's father's money's
    undersecretary's granite's level's wife's fat's Knife's fire's name's
    hell's leg's sun's roulette's cane's guy's kind's baseball's ...
NN+HVD: noun, singular, common + verb 'to have', past tense
    Pa'd
NN+HVZ: noun, singular, common + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    guy's Knife's boat's summer's rain's company's
NN+IN: noun, singular, common + preposition
    buncha
NN+MD: noun, singular, common + modal auxillary
    cowhand'd sun'll
NN+NN: noun, singular, common, hyphenated pair
    stomach-belly
NNS: noun, plural, common
    irregularities presentments thanks reports voters laws legislators
    years areas adjustments chambers $100 bonds courts sales details raises
    sessions members congressmen votes polls calls ...
NNS$: noun, plural, common, genitive
    taxpayers' children's members' States' women's cutters' motorists'
    steelmakers' hours' Nations' lawyers' prisoners' architects' tourists'
    Employers' secretaries' Rogues' ...
NNS+MD: noun, plural, common + modal auxillary
    duds'd oystchers'll
NP: noun, singular, proper
    Fulton Atlanta September-October Durwood Pye Ivan Allen Jr. Jan.
    Alpharetta Grady William B. Hartsfield Pearl Williams Aug. Berry J. M.
    Cheshire Griffin Opelika Ala. E. Pelham Snodgrass ...
NP$: noun, singular, proper, genitive
    Green's Landis' Smith's Carreon's Allison's Boston's Spahn's Willie's
    Mickey's Milwaukee's Mays' Howsam's Mantle's Shaw's Wagner's Rickey's
    Shea's Palmer's Arnold's Broglio's ...
NP+BEZ: noun, singular, proper + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    W.'s Ike's Mack's Jack's Kate's Katharine's Black's Arthur's Seaton's
    Buckhorn's Breed's Penny's Rob's Kitty's Blackwell's Myra's Wally's
    Lucille's Springfield's Arlene's
NP+HVZ: noun, singular, proper + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    Bill's Guardino's Celie's Skolman's Crosson's Tim's Wally's
NP+MD: noun, singular, proper + modal auxillary
    Gyp'll John'll
NPS: noun, plural, proper
    Chases Aderholds Chapelles Armisteads Lockies Carbones French Marskmen
    Toppers Franciscans Romans Cadillacs Masons Blacks Catholics British
    Dixiecrats Mississippians Congresses ...
NPS$: noun, plural, proper, genitive
    Republicans' Orioles' Birds' Yanks' Redbirds' Bucs' Yankees' Stevenses'
    Geraghtys' Burkes' Wackers' Achaeans' Dresbachs' Russians' Democrats'
    Gershwins' Adventists' Negroes' Catholics' ...
NR: noun, singular, adverbial
    Friday home Wednesday Tuesday Monday Sunday Thursday yesterday tomorrow
    tonight West East Saturday west left east downtown north northeast
    southeast northwest North South right ...
NR$: noun, singular, adverbial, genitive
    Saturday's Monday's yesterday's tonight's tomorrow's Sunday's
    Wednesday's Friday's today's Tuesday's West's Today's South's
NR+MD: noun, singular, adverbial + modal auxillary
    today'll
NRS: noun, plural, adverbial
    Sundays Mondays Saturdays Wednesdays Souths Fridays
OD: numeral, ordinal
    first 13th third nineteenth 2d 61st second sixth eighth ninth twenty-
    first eleventh 50th eighteenth- Thirty-ninth 72nd 1/20th twentieth mid-
    19th thousandth 350th sixteenth 701st ...
PN: pronoun, nominal
    none something everything one anyone nothing nobody everybody everyone
    anybody anything someone no-one nothin
PN$: pronoun, nominal, genitive
    one's someone's anybody's nobody's everybody's anyone's everyone's
PN+BEZ: pronoun, nominal + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    nothing's everything's somebody's nobody's someone's
PN+HVD: pronoun, nominal + verb 'to have', past tense
    nobody'd
PN+HVZ: pronoun, nominal + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    nobody's somebody's one's
PN+MD: pronoun, nominal + modal auxillary
    someone'll somebody'll anybody'd
PP$: determiner, possessive
    our its his their my your her out thy mine thine
PP$$: pronoun, possessive
    ours mine his hers theirs yours
PPL: pronoun, singular, reflexive
    itself himself myself yourself herself oneself ownself
PPLS: pronoun, plural, reflexive
    themselves ourselves yourselves
PPO: pronoun, personal, accusative
    them it him me us you 'em her thee we'uns
PPS: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular
    it he she thee
PPS+BEZ: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    it's he's she's
PPS+HVD: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular + verb 'to have', past tense
    she'd he'd it'd
PPS+HVZ: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    it's he's she's
PPS+MD: pronoun, personal, nominative, 3rd person singular + modal auxillary
    he'll she'll it'll he'd it'd she'd
PPSS: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    they we I you ye thou you'uns
PPSS+BEM: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to be', present tense, 1st person singular
    I'm Ahm
PPSS+BER: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to be', present tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    we're you're they're
PPSS+BEZ: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    you's
PPSS+BEZ*: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular, negated
    'tain't
PPSS+HV: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to have', uninflected present tense
    I've we've they've you've
PPSS+HVD: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to have', past tense
    I'd you'd we'd they'd
PPSS+MD: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + modal auxillary
    you'll we'll I'll we'd I'd they'll they'd you'd
PPSS+VB: pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular + verb 'to verb', uninflected present tense
    y'know
QL: qualifier, pre
    well less very most so real as highly fundamentally even how much
    remarkably somewhat more completely too thus ill deeply little overly
    halfway almost impossibly far severly such ...
QLP: qualifier, post
    indeed enough still 'nuff
RB: adverb
    only often generally also nevertheless upon together back newly no
    likely meanwhile near then heavily there apparently yet outright fully
    aside consistently specifically formally ever just ...
RB$: adverb, genitive
    else's
RB+BEZ: adverb + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    here's there's
RB+CS: adverb + conjunction, coordinating
    well's soon's
RBR: adverb, comparative
    further earlier better later higher tougher more harder longer sooner
    less faster easier louder farther oftener nearer cheaper slower tighter
    lower worse heavier quicker ...
RBR+CS: adverb, comparative + conjunction, coordinating
    more'n
RBT: adverb, superlative
    most best highest uppermost nearest brightest hardest fastest deepest
    farthest loudest ...
RN: adverb, nominal
    here afar then
RP: adverb, particle
    up out off down over on in about through across after
RP+IN: adverb, particle + preposition
    out'n outta
TO: infinitival to
    to t'
TO+VB: infinitival to + verb, infinitive
    t'jawn t'lah
UH: interjection
    Hurrah bang whee hmpf ah goodbye oops oh-the-pain-of-it ha crunch say
    oh why see well hello lo alas tarantara rum-tum-tum gosh hell keerist
    Jesus Keeeerist boy c'mon 'mon goddamn bah hoo-pig damn ...
VB: verb, base: uninflected present, imperative or infinitive
    investigate find act follow inure achieve reduce take remedy re-set
    distribute realize disable feel receive continue place protect
    eliminate elaborate work permit run enter force ...
VB+AT: verb, base: uninflected present or infinitive + article
    wanna
VB+IN: verb, base: uninflected present, imperative or infinitive + preposition
    lookit
VB+JJ: verb, base: uninflected present, imperative or infinitive + adjective
    die-dead
VB+PPO: verb, uninflected present tense + pronoun, personal, accusative
    let's lemme gimme
VB+RP: verb, imperative + adverbial particle
    g'ahn c'mon
VB+TO: verb, base: uninflected present, imperative or infinitive + infinitival to
    wanta wanna
VB+VB: verb, base: uninflected present, imperative or infinitive; hypenated pair
    say-speak
VBD: verb, past tense
    said produced took recommended commented urged found added praised
    charged listed became announced brought attended wanted voted defeated
    received got stood shot scheduled feared promised made ...
VBG: verb, present participle or gerund
    modernizing improving purchasing Purchasing lacking enabling pricing
    keeping getting picking entering voting warning making strengthening
    setting neighboring attending participating moving ...
VBG+TO: verb, present participle + infinitival to
    gonna
VBN: verb, past participle
    conducted charged won received studied revised operated accepted
    combined experienced recommended effected granted seen protected
    adopted retarded notarized selected composed gotten printed ...
VBN+TO: verb, past participle + infinitival to
    gotta
VBZ: verb, present tense, 3rd person singular
    deserves believes receives takes goes expires says opposes starts
    permits expects thinks faces votes teaches holds calls fears spends
    collects backs eliminates sets flies gives seeks reads ...
WDT: WH-determiner
    which what whatever whichever whichever-the-hell
WDT+BER: WH-determiner + verb 'to be', present tense, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    what're
WDT+BER+PP: WH-determiner + verb 'to be', present, 2nd person singular or all persons plural + pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    whaddya
WDT+BEZ: WH-determiner + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    what's
WDT+DO+PPS: WH-determiner + verb 'to do', uninflected present tense + pronoun, personal, nominative, not 3rd person singular
    whaddya
WDT+DOD: WH-determiner + verb 'to do', past tense
    what'd
WDT+HVZ: WH-determiner + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    what's
WP$: WH-pronoun, genitive
    whose whosever
WPO: WH-pronoun, accusative
    whom that who
WPS: WH-pronoun, nominative
    that who whoever whosoever what whatsoever
WPS+BEZ: WH-pronoun, nominative + verb 'to be', present, 3rd person singular
    that's who's
WPS+HVD: WH-pronoun, nominative + verb 'to have', past tense
    who'd
WPS+HVZ: WH-pronoun, nominative + verb 'to have', present tense, 3rd person singular
    who's that's
WPS+MD: WH-pronoun, nominative + modal auxillary
    who'll that'd who'd that'll
WQL: WH-qualifier
    however how
WRB: WH-adverb
    however when where why whereby wherever how whenever whereon wherein
    wherewith wheare wherefore whereof howsabout
WRB+BER: WH-adverb + verb 'to be', present, 2nd person singular or all persons plural
    where're
WRB+BEZ: WH-adverb + verb 'to be', present, 3rd person singular
    how's where's
WRB+DO: WH-adverb + verb 'to do', present, not 3rd person singular
    howda
WRB+DOD: WH-adverb + verb 'to do', past tense
    where'd how'd
WRB+DOD*: WH-adverb + verb 'to do', past tense, negated
    whyn't
WRB+DOZ: WH-adverb + verb 'to do', present tense, 3rd person singular
    how's
WRB+IN: WH-adverb + preposition
    why'n
WRB+MD: WH-adverb + modal auxillary
    where'd
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer what is the AT representing sorry im still grasping nltk

Comment: Take a look at the universal POS tags tagset: http://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/ (Particularly, the https://github.com/slavpetrov/universal-pos-tags/blob/master/en-brown.map)

Comment: That's what you should be looking for when you use `brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')`. The `AT` here is particular to the brown tagset.

Comment: so why not use 'NN' instead of 'AT'. Thanks for the source

Comment: Look at the steps carefully, don't just go to the one-liner ;P The `'AT'` is the tag of the determiner "the", then you want to filter the FreqDist depending on the values, not the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: ahhh i see, thanks for the information truly so helpfull

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped =)

Comment: could you just briefly explain what the 'count in' part is achieving